# Posting Data from form (xml) to Zoho CRM with php and cURL

Tags: curl, zoho

I am trying to add a variable to an URL so the XML string content gets posted to Zoho CRM. I thought I can do this with cURL. But nothing happens. I got the xml values from the Zoho CRM API.

```
<?php


$xml_data = '<SalesOrders>'.
'<row no="1">'.
'<FL val="Subject">Zillium - SO</FL>'.
'<FL val="Due Date">2009-03-10</FL>'.
'<FL val="Sub Total">48000.0</FL>'.
'<FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>'.
'<FL val="Adjustment">0.0</FL>'.
'<FL val="Grand Total">48000.0</FL>'.
'<FL val="Billing Address Street">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Shipping Street">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Billing City">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Shipping City">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Billing State">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Shipping State">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Billing Code">223</FL>'.
'<FL val="Shipping Code">223</FL>'.
'<FL val="Billing Country">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Shipping Country">test</FL>'.
'<FL val="Product Details"></FL>'.
'<FL val="Terms and Conditions">Test by Zoho</FL>'.
'<FL val="Description">Test By Zoho</FL>'.
'</row>'.
'</SalesOrders>';


$ch = curl_init("https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/SalesOrders/insertRecords?
authtoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=crmapi             
&newFormat=1&xmlData=");       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

I have searched everywhere on the web to find a solution but nothing works. The

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$zoho_url='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/SalesOrders/insertRecords?'; 

$token="get ur token here";
$data='newFormat=1&authtoken='.$token.'&scope=crmapi&xmlData='.$xml_data;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $zoho_url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error=curl_error($ch);
if($error)
    throw Exception('Error in inserting records to Zoho CRM');
curl_close($ch);
```

Hope this helps :)